# JSON object key value pair parse to spinners Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-volley

**{
    "India": "India",
    "Malaysia": "Malaysia",
    "Mexico": "Mexico"
}**

I need to parse this to spinners.
This is my code and I'm using volley

```
Log.w("Response", response.keys());
                        Iterator<String> keys= response.keys();
                        while (keys.hasNext())
                        {
                            String keyValue = (String)keys.next();
                             try {
                                String valueString = response.getString(keyValue);
                                ArrayAdapter<String> locationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valueString);
                                locationAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                Log.w("valueString KEY", valueString);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
Iterator<String> keys = response.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()) {
    try {
        list.add(response.getString(keys.next()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // ignore me
    }
}
ArrayAdapter<String> locationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
locationAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create an array of keyValue, then you have to pass this array to ArrayAdapter.eg

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
           spinnerArray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout
                                                     .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Or you can use this:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        your_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```